# Format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    int *p = &x;
    *p = 6;

    int **q;
    q = &p;

    int ***r;
    r = &q;

    printf("The value of **q is: %d\n",*q);
```

> ```
> /*  
> This (printf("The value of **q is: %d\n",*q);) statement is giving me an error:  
> warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type  
> ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]. I want to know why it is asking %ls instead of %d  
> and why I'm not able to print the address? 
> */
> ```

```
    printf("The value of **q is: %d\n",**q);
    printf("The value of X is: %d\n",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I hope this post is almost formatted as per requirements.

Comment: `*q` is still a pointer because `q` is declared as `int **q;`

Comment: The value of **q is *q?

Comment: `int **q;` has 2 levels of pointer indirection. It is a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `int`. In order to access the integer at that memory location, you must remove both levels of indirection, e.g. `**q`. The first `'*'` removes one *pointer-to*. The next removes the second *pointer-to* leaving only `int`. If you want to print the pointer address, then see August Karlstrom's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your declarations, the relationships between the various expressions and their types are as follows:

```
   r ==  &q              // int *** == int ***
  *r ==   q == &p        // int **  == int **  == int **
 **r ==  *q ==  p == &x  // int *   == int *   == int *  == int *
***r == **q == *p ==  x  // int     == int     == int    == int
```

The type of `x` is `int`, so the type of the *expression* `&x` is `int *` (pointer to `int`).  The type of `p` is `int *` (pointer to `int`), so the type of the expression `&p` is `int **` (pointer to pointer to `int`).  Similarly, the type of `q` is `int **`, so the type of the expression `&q` is `int ***` (pointer to pointer to pointer to `int`).  Going the other way, the type of `r` is `int ***` (pointer to pointer to pointer to `int`), so the expression `*r` has type `int **`, `**r` has type `int *`, and `***r` has type `int`.

As August points out, the correct way to print a pointer value (of any pointer type) is to use the `%p` conversion specifier and cast the pointer argument to `void *`:

```
printf( "value of x = %d, address of x = %p\n", x, (void *) &x );
printf( "value of p = %p, address of p = %p\n", (void *) p, (void *) &p );
printf( "value of q = %p, address of q = %p\n", (void *) q, (void *) &q );
printf( "value of r = %p, *r = %p, **r = %p, ***r = %d\n", 
  (void *) r, (void *) *r, (void *) **r, ***r );
```

etc.  This is probably the only place you need to explicitly cast a pointer to `void *` in C.

Answer (score 3):

`int **q`:

> q is a pointer to pointer which points to an int

And when you dereference it only one time it gives you a pointer.

`printf("The value of **q is: %d\n",*q);`  has to be `printf("The value of **q is: %d\n",**q);`, if you want an address of int `printf("The address of **q is: %p\n",*q);`

For C declarations you could read [How to read C declarations](https://parrt.cs.usfca.edu/doc/how-to-read-C-declarations.html),  [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) and for practicing [cdecl](https://cdecl.org)

Comment: Another useful link: [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: How to read C declarations is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the format string `%p` to print a pointer. The format specifier `p` expects a void pointer whereas `*q` is an integer pointer so you also need a cast. The cast is needed because a void pointer may have a different size and representation than an integer pointer. Here is the corrected print statement:

```
printf("The value of *q is: %p\n", (void *) *q);
```

Comment: I was following a video tutorial in which the format specifier was %d and it gave the o/p as intended. Is it to do something with IDE? I am using Code Blocks and the tutorial was using Visual Studio.

Comment: @MKSundaram On that specific platform it may have worked by accident but the behavior is undefined. If you enable compiler warnings you will see that the compiler will complain.

Comment: @MKSundaram On the other hand, if you want to print the integer `**q` you (of course) use the format string `%d`.

Comment: I was trying to print address. %p did work for me. I was wondering am I missing something. Thanks for the simple explanation. It was very helpful.

Comment: @MKSundaram *I was wondering am I missing something.*  Yes.  You missed the fact that the video tutorial you watched was ***wrong*** to use `%d` to print a pointer value.

Answer (score -3):

```
int %d / %i
long    %ld
float/double    %lf / %f
char    %c
string (char*)  %s
pointeur (void*)    %p
short   %hd
entier hexadécimal  %x
```